# Python - K clustering, trying to create a 3D cluster

Tags: python

I'm getting this error every-time i launch my code (concerns last part of code) and i have tried multiple time to fix it  without success ->

```
raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (2, 2)
```

It looks there is an issue with the shape of the data being passed to create the datafrom in the `KMeans_Algorithm` function.

`centroids` array has a shape of `(2,3)` but the `dataFrame` creation expects a shape of `(2,2)`, how can I adjust the code to change the shape?

Any chance somebody knows a solution? Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype, is_numeric_dtype

df = pd.read_csv('Mall_Customers.csv')

# Populate list of num and cat variables

num_list = []
cat_list = []

for column in df:
    if is_numeric_dtype(df[column]):

        num_list.append(column)

    elif is_string_dtype(df[column]):

        cat_list.append(column)

print("numeric:", num_list)
print("categorical:", cat_list)

for column in df:

    plt.figure(column, figsize=(5, 5))
    plt.title(column)

    if is_numeric_dtype(df[column]):

        df[column].plot(kind='hist')

    elif is_string_dtype(df[column]):

        # show only top 10 val count in each categorical data

        df[column].value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

# Drop not used variables (cant use Kcluster on categorical data)

df = df.drop(["CustomerID", "Gender"], axis=1)

# transform data into the standard scale


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
for var in ["Age", "Annual Income (k$)", "Spending Score (1-100)"]:
    scaled_var = "scaled_" + var

    model = scaler.fit(df[var].values.reshape(-1, 1))
    df[scaled_var] = model.transform(df[var].values.reshape(-1, 1))
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    plt.title(scaled_var)
    df[scaled_var].plot(kind='hist')
    # Young population/ Average salary + Spending
plt.show()

# 2D Scatter plot

columns = ["scaled_Age", "scaled_Annual Income (k$)", "scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"]
sns.pairplot(df[columns])

# age vs. annual income
# annual income vs. spending score
# age vs. spending income
plt.show()
# 3D Scatter plot

axis_list = ["scaled_Age", "scaled_Annual Income (k$)", "scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"]
x, y, z = axis_list

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")
sc = ax.scatter(df[x], df[y], df[z], s=60)
ax.set_xlabel(x)
ax.set_ylabel(y)
ax.set_zlabel(z)

plt.show()

# define K means algorithm function that return inertia, label centroids and silouhete score


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics

def KMeans_Algorithm(dataset, n):
    clustering_KMeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, random_state=0, algorithm="elkan")
    clustering_KMeans.fit(dataset)

    # create data fram to store centroids

    centroids = clustering_KMeans.cluster_centers_
    centroids_df = pd.DataFrame(centroids, columns=['X', 'Y'])
    # add cluster label for each data point
    label = clustering_KMeans.labels_

    df["label"] = label
    # evaluation metrics for clustering - inertia and silouette score

    inertia = clustering_KMeans.inertia_
    silhouette_score = metrics.silhouette_score(dataset, label)

    return inertia, label, centroids_df, silhouette_score


# Spending vs. Age

X1 = df[["scaled_Age", "scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"]].values
# Spending vs. Annual Income
X2 = df[["scaled_Annual Income (k$)", "scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"]].values
# Spending vs. Age vs Annual Income
X3 = df[["scaled_Age", "scaled_Annual Income (k$)", "scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"]].values

# Spending vs. Age by different numbers of clusters

X1_inertia_values = []
X1_silhouette_scores = []
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

for i in range(2, 11):
    X1_inertia, X1_label, X1_centroids, X1_silhouette = KMeans_Algorithm(X1, i)
    X1_inertia_values.append(X1_inertia)
    X1_silhouette_scores.append(X1_silhouette)

    centroids_df = pd.DataFrame(X1_centroids, columns=['X', 'Y'])
    sub = fig1.add_subplot(330 + i - 1)
    sub.scatter(df["scaled_Age"], df["scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"], s=60, c=df["label"], cmap="RdBu")
    sub.scatter(centroids_df['X'], centroids_df['Y'], s=90, marker=",", color="r")
    sub.set_xlabel("Age")
    sub.set_ylabel("Spending Score (1-100)")

# plot inertia values against number of clusters

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(2, 11), X1_inertia_values)
plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
plt.ylabel("Inertia Values")

# plot Slhouette values against number of clusters

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(2, 11), X1_silhouette_scores)
plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
plt.ylabel("Silhouette Score")

plt.show()

# Spending Score vs. Annual Income by different numbers of clusters
X2_inertia_values = []
X2_silhouette_scores = []
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

for i in range(2, 11):
    X2_centroids: DataFrame
    X2_inertia, X2_label, X2_centroids, X2_silhouette = KMeans_Algorithm(X2, i)
    X2_inertia_values.append(X2_inertia)
    X2_silhouette_scores.append(X2_silhouette)

centroids_df = pd.DataFrame( X2_centroids, columns=['X', 'Y'])

sub = fig2.add_subplot(330 + i - 1)
sub.scatter(df["scaled_Annual Income (k$)"], df["scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"], s=60, c=df["label"], cmap="RdBu")
sub.scatter(centroids_df['X'], centroids_df['Y'], s=90, marker=",", color="r")
sub.set_xlabel("Annual Income (k$)")
sub.set_ylabel("Spending Score (1-100)")

# plot inertia values against number of clusters

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(2, 11), X2_inertia_values, '-')
plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
plt.ylabel("Inertia Values")

# plot Slhouette values against number of clusters

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(2, 11), X2_silhouette_scores, '-')
plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
plt.ylabel("Silhouette Score")

plt.show()

X3_inertia_values = []
X3_silhouette_scores = []
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

for i in range(2, 11):
    X3_inertia, X3_label, X3_centroids, X3_silhouette = KMeans_Algorithm(X3, i)
    X3_inertia_values.append(X3_inertia)
    X3_silhouette_scores.append(X3_silhouette)

    centroids_df = pd.DataFrame(X3_centroids, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])  # Adjusted to match the shape of centroids

    ax = fig.add_subplot(330 + i - 1, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(df["scaled_Age"], df["scaled_Annual Income (k$)"], df["scaled_Spending Score (1-100)"], s=30,
               c=df["label"], cmap="RdBu")
    ax.scatter(centroids_df['X'], centroids_df['Y'], centroids_df['Z'], s=90, marker=",", color="r")
    ax.set_xlabel("Age")
    ax.set_ylabel("Annual Income (k$)")
    ax.set_zlabel("Spending Score (1-100)")

# Plot inertia values against number of clusters

plt.figure(11, figsize=(15, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(2, 11), X3_inertia_values, '-')
plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
plt.ylabel("Inertia Values")

# Plot Silhouette values against number of clusters

plt.figure(12, figsize=(15, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(2, 11), X3_silhouette_scores, '-')
plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
plt.ylabel("Silhouette Score")

plt.show()
```

I tried to rearrange the centroids array to change its shape but it is not working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).